# doesn't Jetty server support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web module specificaton?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jetty

I created a version 3.0 of J2ee web module with resin4, now I need to use jetty, so I installed eclipse plugin of jetty 6, but when I `new server` with it, eclipse point that `The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web module specification`, is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Jetty 6 is very old and was marked End of Life back in 2010.

Use Jetty 8 or Jetty 9 for Servlet 3.0 support.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

Comment: but when I download plugin of jetty in eclipse, jetty 6 is installed?

Comment: we have little or no control over what a jetty plugin in eclipse is doing, we haven't provided one in years now